# How to use UIScrollView with ViewControllers from Storyboard

Tags: uiscrollview, xcode4.2, uipagecontrol, uistoryboard, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How would I use a UIScroll view (much like the main iPhone screen) with the page control at the bottom, pass UIViewControllers?

I have three UIViewControllers,that I would like the user to swipe back and forth.  However these are already created in a Storyboard.  I want the entry point to be the middle viewController and have the user wipe left and right to get to the 1st and 3rd view controller.

Am I right to assume that swiping is built into scroll view's with paging enabled?

Thanks in advance

-PaulS.